# Custom items in enumerate, labels, and references

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, labels

The following MWE should display

> (2) Test
>
> (2') Test
>
> Reference to (2').

but the last line only says "Reference to  ", with no reference. How can I achieve the desired effect ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[(2)]\label{item:2} Test
  \item[(2')]\label{item:2p} Test
  \end{enumerate}
  Reference to \ref{item:2p}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\item[foo]` does not provide the correct reference label here, since `enumi` counter is not at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `\item[foo]` does not increase the `enumi` counter (it is the `enumerate` environment on 1st level here) with `\refstepcounter`, the `\label` command cannot apply the correct reference 'number' -- this is generated by `\refstepcounter` and stored in the `\@currentlabel` macro -- no `\refstepcounter` means that `\@currentlabel` is empty here.

An approach can be to use a wrapper command, say `\myitem` and store the argument as the `\@currentlabel` value. This way, `\label` works as expected.

Since `\@currentlabel` is an `@` - letter - command, the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair has to be wrapped around the definition of `\myitem`.

The name of `\myitem` is somewhat arbitray, of course, as long as no name of an already existing command sequence or primitive is used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
\item[#1]\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \myitem{(2)}\label{item:2} Test
  \myitem{(2')}\label{item:2p} Test
  \end{enumerate}
  Reference to \ref{item:2} and \ref{item:2p}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Catching `\item[...]` would be possible too, but this is easier, in my point of view

Comment: ```\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myitem}[2][]{%
\item[#2#1]\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}%
}
\makeatother```
you can use this slight modification you want to use let's say `Q1.` but don't show up `.` in the reference label. You will need to use `\myitem[.]{Q1}`.