# Wrong label when I use customized \item and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, enumitem

First I refer to this answer : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328393/180617 to get an ref-able label of customized `\item`, but when I want to use `hyperref` package to click and jump, things went strange.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\it@m\item
\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{ o }{%
\IfValueTF{#1}{\it@m[#1]\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}}{\it@m}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 1
        \item 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[start=3]
        \item [1st] \label{1st} first
        \item [2nd] \label{2nd} second
        \item \label{3rd} third
    \end{enumerate}
    \ref{1st}, \ref{2nd}, \ref{3rd}
\end{document}
```

after 2 times of `pdflatex`, I got the "right" pdf file

[image]

However when I click `1st` and `2nd`, it will always jump to the first `enumerate`'s first item.

And `main.aux` writes

```
\newlabel{1st}{{1st}{1}{}{Item.1}{}}
\newlabel{2nd}{{2nd}{1}{}{Item.1}{}}
\newlabel{3rd}{{3}{1}{}{Item.2}{}}
```

Why would this happen and how to fix it?

**Edit**: Thanks for @werner 's answer. However I found that if I use a  `\ref` as the label, hyperlinks still went wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\it@m\item% Store \item inside \it@m
\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{ o }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\it@m[#1]\phantomsection\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}}
    {\it@m}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item\label{test} 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[start=3]
  \item [\ref{test}] \label{1st} first
  \item [2nd] \label{2nd} second
  \item \label{3rd} third
\end{enumerate}

\ref{1st}, \ref{2nd}, \ref{3rd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

when I click on the `2` on the bottom, I wish it to jump to the line `first`. But it jumped to the original line `2`. I thought it caused by a double `ref`. However, when I test this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \section{One}\label{one}
    test
    \section{Two \ref{one}}\label{two}
    \ref{two}
\end{document}
```

hyperlinks work fine. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue `\item[<lab>]` with an optional argument, there is no counter stepped. And this counter stepping is crucial to also set the appropriate [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) target (internally this is done by stepping the counter using `\refstepcounter`). To get around this, issue `\phantomsection` in the `T`rue branch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\it@m\item% Store \item inside \it@m
\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{ o }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\it@m[#1]\phantomsection\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}}
    {\it@m}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[start=3]
  \item [1st] \label{1st} first
  \item [2nd] \label{2nd} second
  \item \label{3rd} third
\end{enumerate}

\ref{1st}, \ref{2nd}, \ref{3rd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I met another problem. I complemented it in the question.

Comment: @Syvshc: Yeah... you're jumping around in circles here with a reference of a reference. For such leap-frogged referencing you need to step in a bit; automation won't help you here. See [this solution](https://pastebin.com/raw/N2Qj7TG6).